# using svnsync to auto synchronize between svn repository and a specified folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Could anyone point me to a sample svnsync auto synchronize script/batch file to synchronize between svn repository and a specified folder in a windows environment.

What I want to achieve is a sync between a svn source repository and a predefined folder so that whenever a file in the svn source repository is added/updated the changes are automatically pushed/replicated on the specified folder on a predefined folder on the users PC.

I tried reading on post-commmit hook but I cannot see this option in my SVN repository. All this is new to me, so perhaps an example would help me understand it better.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: svnsync synchronizes 2 repositories, basically a master and a mirror.  you will need to do a post-commit hook or utilize an external package like jenkins or something

Answer (score 1):

The post-commit hook could indeed be what you are looking for. It's a script named 'post-commit' that resides in your repository directory (not the workdirectory) in the subdirectory 'hooks'. It gets executed after a (successful) commit to the repository (as long as it has execute permissions). You are free in what the script does and in what language it is written but keep in mind that it is executed by the actual committer (not 'root' or something).

Regarding your problem, it may be sufficient to write a little shell script that updates a target directory. If the target directory is a working dir something like `/path/to/svn update /path/to/working-dir` should do.

Depending on your Subversion installation there may also be some example hooks in the hooks directory of your repository. Have a look at these to get an idea what a hook does.

Comment: I am looking to Automatically sync the Master Repository to Slave(Backup) Repository. Automatically whenever the user commits, it should sync the files. As I know SVN - Hook will do the task for me, and the task is 1. Define the slave/backup repository. Here you suggested